# Why won't my image centre?

Tags: html

Why won't my image block centre?

Here is my css

```
.heading {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

And my image is clearly on the right side of the page, not the centre

[image]

Comment: Because the margin doesnt take into account the width of your image. That is 50% to the start of your image not the middle.
if you want to do it that way it needs to be margin-left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; (or half as wide as the image is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not work because `margin-left: 50%` is not how you would center an object. All this does is put 50% of your screen on the left side of your image. The correct way to do this is like this:

```
.header {
margin: 0 auto;
width: [image width];
}
```

in the stylesheet. This will tell the browser to put 0 margin on the top and bottom of your image, and to automatically center the margin on the left and right side. You also need to add a `width: [width];` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="heading">
 <img src="img url">
</div>
```

**style**

```
.heading{
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: 50%` does not do center.

The correct code is `margin: 0 auto;`. I'm assuming this class `heading` is placed on the image itself. Otherwise your container will fill the whole space and margin 0 auto won't move it at all.

Margin with 50% on the left is going to push the left side of your image exactly 50% across the page. There is a lot more to margin and depending on how you have your image positioned depends on what trait you have to apply.

Comment: For auto margin to work you also need to specify the width of the element; In this case the image.

Comment: true. but correct me if I'm wrong, most the time images have a width that allows the margin auto to work.

Comment: Yes; But I was thinking if he wanted to center a full div sometime; then he needs the width property :)
But if it's only an image he's going to center you're right!

Answer (score 0):

I too had that same problem a while ago when I was trying to center some of my items.

I was able to do it with this code here:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2WsC.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also, you can optionally add a little addition to the CSS to make the text be centered, so that if you wish to centre that there is no more work needed. That CSS would be

```
    text-align: center;
```

Just add that to your CSS after the margin element.

Hope that this helped you.